# Reading JSON values from web browser?

Tags: json, unity-game-engine

I have a random JSON generated online and I am able to print all the values. But how do I read each array separately? For example, the below JSON contains different attributes, how do I read the string `name` that is an array containing 4 values.

JSON reader:

```
public class JsonHelper
{

    public static T[] getJsonArray<T>(string json)
    {
        string newJson = "{ \"array\": " + json + "}";
        Wrapper<T> wrapper = JsonUtility.FromJson<Wrapper<T>>(newJson);
        return wrapper.array;

    }
    [System.Serializable]
    private class Wrapper<T>
    {
        public T[] array;
    }
}

 [System.Serializable]

public class RootObject
{
    public string name;
    public string height;
    public string mass ;
}
```

The below script is used to access the JSON online through RESTApi GET service. I am able to receive the whole text but how I read one single value of `name` or `height` or `mass`?

Script:

```
using UnityEngine.Networking;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.IO;

public class GetData : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        StartCoroutine(GetNames());
    }

    IEnumerator GetNames()
    {
        string GetNameURL = "https://swapi.co/api/people/1/?format=json";
        using(UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Get(GetNameURL))
        {
        //  www.chunkedTransfer = false;
            yield return www.Send();
            if(www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError)
            {
                Debug.Log(www.error);
            }

            else

            {
                if(www.isDone)
                {
                    string jsonResult = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(www.downloadHandler.data);
                    Debug.Log(jsonResult); //I am getting the result here

                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your API call to 'https://swapi.co/api/people/1/?format=json' returns a single object, not an array.

So after you get your json, you can access name and height etc like:

```
        if (www.isDone)
        {
            string jsonResult = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(www.downloadHandler.data);
            Debug.Log(jsonResult); //I am getting the result here

            RootObject person = JsonUtility.FromJson<RootObject>(jsonResult);
            // then you can access each property
            Debug.Log(person.name);
            Debug.Log(person.height);
        }
```

Comment: Thank you. I was accessing it as an array. Since the `person.name` has only one value and I have defined it as  `public string name;` What happens if there are more than one name and should I define it as `public string[] name;` or due to the changed structure of JSON, my script should also alter?